# Rails: error when adding two ActiveSupport::Duration objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, operators, ruby-on-rails-5, activesupport

In a Rails console (Rails 5.0.1), I have an `ActiveSupport::Duration` object representing a time interval, in this case 12 minutes:

`x = ActiveSupport::Duration.parse("P0Y0M0DT0H12M")`

I'd like to add a random amount of minutes to it, so I create another `ActiveSupport::Duration` object:

`y = ActiveSupport::Duration.parse("P0Y0M0DT0H3M")`

According to [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-2B), I would expect to be able to add them simply using a `+` operator and do `x+y`, but that results in:

`NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for {:years=>0, :months=>0, :days=>0, :hours=>0, :minutes=>12}:Hash`

Where am I going wrong? Why does it think they are Hashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug introduced by the [parts being hashified](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/32f215c3014e580e512db5e8772d0deadf3d6497), which appears to be a [partial backport from 5.1 to 5.0.3](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/19c450d5d99275924254b2041b6ad470fdaa1f93). You can update your Rails version to 5.1.x, or coerce the values back to numbers first.